# toggle classList ('open') is working and appear in inspect element, but the web is not showing the style

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

i want to adding class .open using toggle in .nav after click #menu-icon, the class 'open' is appear in the inspect element after i click the #menu-icon, but the .nav is not showing any style in .open. Why should i do?

ps : i used bootstrap to make the nav

HTML

```
<!-- logo -->
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo g's shop">
    </div>
    <i class="ri-menu-line" id="menu-icon"></i>

<!-- nav -->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill m4">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active .bg-white" aria-current="page" href="#">ALL ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">SMARTPHONES</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">LAPTOPS</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10001;
    top: 65px;
    right: 30px;
    width: 270px;
    background-color: #f3efef;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all .50s ease;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-item {
    margin-top: -2px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#menu-icon {
    display: block;
}

.nav .open {
    left: 0;
}
```

JS

```
let menu = document.querySelector('#menu-icon');
let navbar = document.querySelector('.nav');

menu.addEventListener("click", function() {
    navbar.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

i expect that the ".nav .open" is working a.k.a ".nav" is dissapear (become left: 0;) after i click the #menu-icon, better using jquery instead of vanilla js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is not working, is just your CSS selector.

Your code here:

```css
.nav .open {
    left: 0;
}
```

would target a child element of nav with class open.

What you want here is to target nav when it has class open:

```css
/*  Note there is no space */
.nav.open {
    left: 0;
}
```